# How to find application port running in yarn?. as yarn pick port dynamically

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How to find application port running in yarn? Yarn is assigning port dynamically to application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Apache Slider](https://slider.incubator.apache.org) project. It should do exactly what you need. The feature you are looking for is called [Service Registry](https://slider.incubator.apache.org/design/registry/a_YARN_service_registry.html)

> Allow clients of a YARN application to locate the service instance and its service ports (web, IPC, REST...) efficiently even on a large YARN cluster